# Converting Pytorch model with NonZero operations to TensorRT

Tags: pytorch, converters, onnx, tensorrt

I'm trying to convert Pytorch model containing NonZero operations to TRT.

I've successfully saved it as ONNX, but neither TensorRT support the operation natively nor existing converters like https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorrt

Could you please advice how I can deal with it maybe by changing the operation to Where or Equal + Logical Not?

Comment: What is the offending function and how are you using it?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean under offending function?

Comment: I'm trying to convert the CrowdDet model https://github.com/Purkialo/CrowdDet

Comment: Please post your stack error trace and the 'offending' (meaning that is raising the error) function, specifically.